# examining audio file alternative to spotlight

Tags: cocoa, audio, qtkit, spotlight

i'm looking for an efficient alternative to grabbing **audio file attributes** in case spotlight is turned off.

**Spotlight's MDItem** attributes: `kMDItemDurationSeconds, kMDItemAudioEncodingApplication, kMDItemAudioBitRate, kMDItemAudioSampleRate,kMDItemAudioChannelCount, kMDItemCodecs`, are possible.

however **QTKit's movieAttributes** (if the file can be a QTMovie type), are not as complete, only `QTMovieDurationAttribute` fills my spec.

should i use **Audio Format Services** : `OSStatus AudioFormatGetProperty`, or is there something else, perhaps more light-weight that will suffice  in the absence of MDItem information ?

i don't need to modify or play any files, i only need to know the property values.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get attributes from the audio track's media, not the movie. Here is an example of how to get duration in seconds.

```
for (QTTrack* track in [movie tracks])
{
    QTMedia* trackMedia = [track media];

    if ([trackMedia hasCharacteristic:QTMediaCharacteristicAudio])
    {
        QTTime mediaDuration = [(NSValue*)[trackMedia attributeForKey:QTMediaDurationAttribute] QTTimeValue];
        long long mediaDurationScaleValue = mediaDuration.timeScale;
        long long mediaDurationTimeValue = mediaDuration.timeValue;
        result = (double)mediaDurationTimeValue / (double)mediaDurationScaleValue;
        break;
    }
}
```

`[trackMedia mediaAttributes]` will give you other available attributes of the audio.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not afraid of using the Terminal, mdls is probably the tool for you:

```
mdls /path/toYour/file
```

Comment: no terminal fear here, but i'm wanting to know how i can programmatically get the audio file attributes besides spotlight -- which the user could have turned off. sorry for not being clear.